$Z$ bosons coupling to other $Z$ bosons
I'm learning about Higgs boson production at the moment. One way that it's produced is by 'vector boson associated production' or VH, which has this Feynman diagram:

What I'm wondering is: how can $Z$ bosons couple to other $Z$ bosons, as shown here? I thought that since the $Z$ boson is neutral and has $0$ weak isospin, it couldn't couple to another $Z$ boson. Where have I gone wrong in my understanding/knowledge?

It is massive, so it interacts via the Higgs field.

@JeanbaptisteRoux I understand why the Z boson couples to the Higgs boson, but why can the Z boson couple to the other Z boson? Or are they meant to be the same Z boson?

A vertex can be read in different orientations. Sometimes it represents a Higgs disintegrating into two Z bosons, sometimes it represents a Z boson Bremsstrahlung-ing a Higgs.

@JeanbaptisteRoux Ah that makes sense. Thanks!

Your SM text presumably has all couplings hZZ and h$W^+ W^-$. for example, the standard text of TP Cheng and LF Li, Gauge theory of elementary particle physics, has them on p 511,
 where $\phi_1$ stands for h,
$$
\Phi '\equiv \begin{pmatrix}\phi^+\\ (h+i\phi^0)/\sqrt 2\end{pmatrix},
$$
the other three $\phi$ s being the goldstons eaten by the three vector bosons in the Higgs mechanism. You can tell  the latter vertex  violates both weak isospin and weak hypercharge, but preserves electric charge, since the v.e.v. does.
The Z is electrically neutral, but so is the h. It couples to just about everything but the photon!

Thanks for this!
